# Getting specific columns from an INCLUDE statement with EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**I want to get only specific columns from a query in EF when using an INCLUDE statement** instead of bringing back all the columns.

**In addition, what if I also wanted to bring back a shorter result set from my Customers object as well.**

**Is there a way to do this?**

Here is my query:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customerProjectsList = GetCustomerProjects();
    customerProjectsList.Dump();
}

public List<Customer> GetCustomerProjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTech DbContext = new YeagerTech())
                {
                    var customer = DbContext.Customers.Include("Projects");

                    return customer;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

### EDIT

I've been trying to use the following query, but get an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Here is the query:
void Main()
{
    List customerProjectsList = GetCustomerProjects();
    customerProjectsList.Dump();
}

```
public List<CustomerDTO> GetCustomerProjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTech DbContext = new YeagerTech())
                {
                    var customerlist = DbContext.Customers.Select(s =>
                        new CustomerDTO()
                        {
                            CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                            Projects =
                                from p in Projects
                                where p.CustomerID == s.CustomerID && p.Quote != null
                                select new Project { Description = p.Description, Quote = p.Quote }
                        }).ToList<Project>();

                    return customerlist.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

If I run this same query in LINQPad as a C# statement instead of a C# program, the query results get produced fine.

I am just going bonkers over this simple way to try and get a hierarchal list back with specific columns.

```
var result = (from c in Customers
select new
{
    c.CustomerID,
    Projects =
        from p in Projects
        where p.CustomerID == c.CustomerID && p.Quote != null
        select new { p.Description, p.Quote }
});
result.Dump();
```

Comment: you can do that by using projection

Comment: replace ToList<Project>(); with ToList();

Comment: Phillip, with all due respect, there has to be a very simple explanation why I'm able to execute the query just fine as a C# statement, but not as a C# program.

Comment: Philip, I already went down that road with just the ToList() and am getting the same error.....

Comment: remove the ToList() altogether, there should be only one at the end. You have 2. By the way you have altered now your question to something entirely different. You should have given this detail from the beginning or created a new question. The moment you use ToList it becomes a normal linq query and it is not IQueryable anymore. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need include; if you have navigation properties between `Customers` and `Projects` you can project to new objects:

```
  var customers = (from c in DbContext.Customers
                   select new
                   {
                       FirstName = c.FirstName,
                       ProjectName = c.Project.Name

                   }).ToList().Select(x => new Customer
                   {
                       FirstName = x.FirstName,
                       Project = new Project()
                       {
                           Name = x.ProjectName
                       }
                   }).ToList();
```

This will return a list of `Customers` where only the first name is populated and each customer will contain a `Project` property with the name populated. This is great for performance as the query sent by EF to your database will be short and will return a result set quickly.

**Edit**:

Taking into account that `Projects` is an `ICollection`, I think the most maintenable thing to do would be to create a couple of [DTOs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5):

```
public CustomerDTO
{
     public int CustomerId;
     public List<ProjectDTO> projects;
}

public ProjectDTO
{
     public string Description;
     public string Quote;
}
```

and project to them like so:

```
var qry = (from c in context.Customers
                       select new CustomerDTO()
                       {
                           CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                           Projects = (from pr in context.Projects
                                       where c.ProjectId equals pr.Id
                                       select new ProjectDTO
                                       { 
                                            Description = pr.Description,
                                            Quote = pr.Quote
                                       }).ToList()
                       });
```

Comment: Circular, if you check my EDIT in my first post, you'll notice that the query runs fine in a C# statement, but not in a C# program with LINQPad. All my models are setup properly. I'll edit your post and show you my models.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Circular, I think I got it... When I'm able to post my edit, please check it out for one more piece of additional help with getting all the columns back. You'll see what I'm talking about in my edit....

Comment: Circular, I bet I know why the extra columns are coming in (even though they are unpopulated).

It's because my Model has all the properties for that class in them! If I only include the properties that I want in my Model, only those will be returned!


Thanks so much for your help in pointing me to the right direction. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use projection to limit the columns that are retrieved. Lots of examples of projection can be found on the internet a short example is like this :

```
DateTime twoDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
var groupSummaries = _recipeContext.Groups.OrderBy(g => g.Name)
    .Select(g => new GroupSummaryModel{
        Id = g.Id,
        Name = g.Name,
        Description = g.Description,
        NumberOfUsers = g.Users.Count(),
        NumberOfNewRecipes = g.Recipes.Count(r => r.PostedOn > twoDaysAgo)
    });
```

I took it from here :
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/02/09/writing-efficient-queries-with-entity-framework-code-first-part-2.aspx

The point is to use the new mechanism if needed multiple times. Here it is used with new GroupSummaryModel.

EDIT

```
var qry = (from c in context.Customers
                       select new CustomerDTO()
                       {
                           CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                           Projects = (from pr in context.Projects
                                       where c.ProjectId equals pr.Id
                                       select new ProjectDTO
                                       { 
                                            Description = pr.Description,
                                            Quote = pr.Quote
                                       }) //--> no tolist here
                       }).ToList(); //--> only here
```

Comment: This won't compile if `CustomerDTO` contains a `List<ProjectDTO>`

Comment: hm, but the toList should be avoided otherwise you mix up iqueryable with normal linq. You want the query to be handled by the server, not the client.